# How to run through array on Javascript?

Tags: javascript, ionic5

I'm stuck retrieving all values from capacitor storage on Ionic 5, I'm retrieving all the time **ZoneAwarePromise** or **Array Iterator**, how to deal with it?

Thank you

//MAIN.ts

```
ngOnInit() {    
    let vaya = this.storage.keys()
    .then(result => {
      return result
    });
    vaya.then(data => {
      for (let item of data) {
        console.log(this.storage.getItem(item))
      }
      
    })
  }
```

//SERVICE STORAGE.ts

```
async keys() {
    const { keys } = await Storage.keys();
    console.log('Got keys: ', keys);
    return keys
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Capacitor Storage is asynchronous so to retrieve all the values it has you need to:

0. Make sure Capacitor has initialized
1. Obtain the keys
2. Write a loop that can do async processing

This should work (this will retrieve data sequentially):

```
ngOnInit() {  
    let values = [];  
    this.storage.keys().then(async (keys) => {
      for (let key of keys) {
        let value = await this.storage.get(key)
        values.push(value)
      };
    });
  }
```

You can also make the promises run in parallel:

```
  ngOnInit() {  
    let values = [];  
    this.storage.keys().then(async (keys) => {
      const promises = keys.map(key => this.storage.get(key))
      values = await Promise.all(promises);
    });
  }
```

Comment: Thank you i did it, can you tell me how to see the result at the same moment? i have to refresh the page to see the changes

Comment: Also it would be nice if i can ordered them by id (1,2,3...)

Comment: hm can you elaborate? by see result you mean console or?

Comment: i meant in the app, when its already saved on the storage, in other tabs should appear the new one, but only appears when its refreshed the app(F5 on browser), oh sorry about the numbers, the key is :0,1,2,3 and the value is the text, then i just want to make sure it's ordered by numbers

Comment: nothing? i still need why i need to refresh it to see the new result

Comment: Hey @M.Mariscal since its isolated issue - can you post a new question for it, I will gladly take a look